# ArgumentError (string contains null byte) in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, utf-8

I'm sending a video file from Android to Rails using the `multipart/form-data` content type. Initially I was using PHP, where it worked flawlessly (so I am assuming the Android part is not the problem) but I later changed to using Rails. The video file has been converted to bytes and sent to the server.

In Rails initially I was getting this error:

```
ArgumentError (invalid byte sequence in UTF-8)
```

After doing a lot of Google search I used the library [rack_sanitizable](https://github.com/whitequark/rack-utf8_sanitizer), then added this to `config/application.rb`:

```
config.middleware.insert 0, Rack::UTF8Sanitizer,  sanitizable_content_types: ['multipart/form-data']
```

After adding that, I now get this error

```
ArgumentError (string contains null byte)
```

I have done a Google search but just couldn't find a solution.

```
@user = User.find(params[:user_id])
submission = Submission.new(create_params)
# submission = Submission.new(:videos => params[:videos])
  
return api_error(status: 422, errors: submission.errors.full_messages) unless submission.valid?

submission.save!
render(
  json: submission,
  status: 201,
  location: api_v1_user_submissions_path(@user.id)
) 
render plain: "success"

def create_params
# params.require(:submission).permit(
#   :interview_videos, :status, {videos: []}
# ).delete_if{ |k,v| v.nil?}
  params.permit(:videos, :user_id)
end
```

Comment: What is the actual submitted data? Are you the php version wasn't just silently ignoring/inserting invalid data?

Comment: Am I missing something, but where is rails code that works with the video file? Or is it not a rails part, and you're taking about some other server that process the video? Where do you save the file to exactly? What's your model code and database for storage?

Comment: Will update the code, it's been handled by carrierwave